# How to determine dependencies for VB6 project?

Tags: vb6, setup-deployment

I am having troubles creating an installer package for a VB6 project.

When I try to install the package created by the Package and Deployment Wizard there are errors when trying to copy and register some of the files (some files are in use, some say there is an error when trying to register).

I would like to do away with these wizards and try to find out what files are needed and use a third party installer like InnoSetup, but I need to know what files should be included.

What is the best way of going about this for a VB6 project?

Comment: You *are* logged on with administrator privileges when you run this installation package, right? Just checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "How Do I Install..." section of the [inno faq](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php) details how to install the VB runtime files & depending on your needs the common controls and MDAC. (The OCX method is also the one to use for ActiveX DLLs).

Looking at any components from the IDEs toolbox/References dialog that you have added over and above the defaults will show you what extra dependencies you have. (As will looking @ the files generated by the P&DW)

Comment: You can also try unchecking things in the components and references lists. It will remove dependencies that were added but are no longer in use.