# vb6 in win 11 fails with object library not registered. which object is failing

Tags: vb6

vb6 program runs in win 10, both IDE and .exe.

program compiles on both systems

program fails on win 11 but doesn't identify which library is at fault. dependancy checker is no help. error occurs immediately upon start so debug trapping reveals nothing.

Comment: Did you install it using Package and Deployment Wizard (on addin menu).

Comment: Have you read these other questions? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51271331/3195477 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031657/how-to-determine-dependencies-for-vb6-project